# Using R to extract data from a dataframe and store data in unknown number of new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-extraction

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A=1:20, 
                  B=c(2,1.8,1.6,1.8,4,6,8,10,12,10,8,6,13,14,15,16,16.5,15,14,13))
mutate(df, C = B - lag(B))
A   B     C
1   2.0   NA
2   1.8 -0.2
3   1.6 -0.2
4   1.8  0.2
5   4.0  2.2
6   6.0  2.0
7   8.0  2.0
8   10.0  2.0
9   12.0  2.0
10  10.0 -2.0
11  8.0 -2.0
12  6.0 -2.0
13  13.0  7.0
14  14.0  1.0
15  15.0  1.0
16  16.0  1.0
17  16.5 -0.5
18  15.0 -1.0
19  14.0 -1.0
20  13.0 -1.0
```

And I want to extract out the sequences of minus values where there are 3 or more consecutively together and put in a separate column. So for example put the values from (col C)row 10, 11, 12 in a new column and row 17, 18,19,20 in another new column. This dataframe is huge so I dont know how many new columns I will have. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this only for column C or for every column?

Comment: Yes, only column C

Comment: @akrun - do you mean more than 3 values consecutively? if so, that would be a new column of data

Comment: Sorry, that should be 16.5 in the B col - I've updated it there now. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `rleid` to create a run-length-id grouping based on the `sign` of the column 'C' i.e. those adjacent elements with same `sign` will have same grouping 'id' and it gets incremented when there is a difference in `sign`.  Then, we create the columns based on the count (`n()`) value to be particular number i.e. 3 or 4

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   mutate(C = B - lag(B)) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(sign(C))) %>%
  mutate(newC3 = if(n() ==3 && all(C < 0)) C else NA,
         newC4 = if(n() == 4 && all(C < 0) C else NA)
```

---

To make this automated, an option is `pivot_wider` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format after creating the grouping id with `rleid` and replaceing the values that are not negative to `NA`.  In this way, we get only the blocks of negative values to be in a separate column

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(C = B - lag(B)) %>%
   mutate(grp = str_c('C', rleid(sign(C))), 
     C1 = case_when(C >=0 ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ C)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = C1)%>%
   select(where(~ sum(!is.na(.)) > 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 6
#       A     B      C     C2    C4    C7
#   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   2   NA     NA        NA    NA
# 2     2   1.8 -0.200 -0.200    NA    NA
# 3     3   1.6 -0.200 -0.200    NA    NA
# 4     4   1.8  0.200 NA        NA    NA
# 5     5   4    2.2   NA        NA    NA
# 6     6   6    2     NA        NA    NA
# 7     7   8    2     NA        NA    NA
# 8     8  10    2     NA        NA    NA
# 9     9  12    2     NA        NA    NA
#10    10  10   -2     NA        -2    NA
#11    11   8   -2     NA        -2    NA
#12    12   6   -2     NA        -2    NA
#13    13  13    7     NA        NA    NA
#14    14  14    1     NA        NA    NA
#15    15  15    1     NA        NA    NA
#16    16  16    1     NA        NA    NA
#17    17  16    0     NA        NA    NA
#18    18  15   -1     NA        NA    -1
#19    19  14   -1     NA        NA    -1
#20    20  13   -1     NA        NA    -1
```

NOTE: The column names 'C2', 'C4', 'C7' are based on the ids created with `rleid`.  If we wanted to rename, then it can be done with `rename_with` or `rename_at`

```
...
  %>%
   rename_at(vars(matches('^C\\d+')), ~ str_c('C', seq_along(.)))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the automated version please - really powerful. thanks

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks again

Comment: By the way, lets say it was 5 consecutive rows - how would I change it to 5 (instead of 3 currently) Thanks

Comment: @user1655130 in the first option, it is just to make use of `if(n() ==5 && all(C < 0)) C else NA` and in second case, you want `group_by(grp) %>% mutate(C1 = case_when(C < 0 & n() ==5  ~ C))`